# How to create knockout text with a non black/white background?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create knockout text like the codepen below, [this](https://codepen.io/rebelchris/pen/WNxQmpd) codepen works just fine when the background colour is set to pure white, or pure black, but as soon you change

```
background: #ffff;
```

to, for example,

```
background: #f5f;
```

The background image leaks through for some reason, like so:
[image]
How do I do this whilst using any colour, without the background image bleeding through?

**Snippet Example (taken from https://codepen.io/rebelchris/pen/WNxQmpd ):**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.background {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101162946-4377e57745c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1957&q=80")
    center;
  background-size: cover;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <h1>GALAXY</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Also worth noting-- I'm not sure that [tag:twitter-bootstrap] or [tag:sass] are actually applicable here...

Comment: Look `mix-blend-mode: lighten;` on [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode), it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something similar and used the css background-clip property

the background is associated with the h1 element rather than the body

you wouldnt need the `.background` class in your example above

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101162946-4377e57745c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1957&q=80") center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Snippet example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F5F;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 15vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465101162946-4377e57745c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1957&q=80") center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>GALAXY</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer-- I added a snippet to show it in action.  It is worth noting that while [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) appears to be standard and supported unprefixed now, [`text-fill-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color) is "non-standard," and thus should be used with caution, with good fallbacks provided.